# Query on VHDL generics in packages

Tags: vhdl

I have written a simple VHDL code to add two matrices containing 32 bit floating point numbers. The matrix dimensions have been defined in a package. Currently, I specify the matrix dimensions in the vhdl code and use the corresponding type from the package. However, I would like to use generic in the design to deal with matrices of different dimensions. For this I would have to somehow use the right type defined in the package. How do I go about doing this?
My current VHDL code is as below.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use work.mat_pak.all;

entity newproj is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clr : in  STD_LOGIC;
           start : in  STD_LOGIC;
           A_in : in  t2;
           B_in : in  t2;
           AplusB : out  t2;
           parallel_add_done : out  STD_LOGIC);
end newproj;

architecture Behavioral of newproj is
COMPONENT add
  PORT (
    a : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    b : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    sclr : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ce : IN STD_LOGIC;
    result : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    rdy: OUT STD_LOGIC
  );
END COMPONENT;


signal temp_out: t2 := (others=>(others=>(others=>'0')));
signal add_over: t2bit:=(others=>(others=>'0'));
signal check_all_done,init_val: std_logic:='0';
begin
    init_val <= '1';
    g0: for k in 0 to 1 generate
                g1: for m in 0 to 1 generate
                            add_instx: add port map(A_in(k)(m), B_in(k)(m),     clk, clr, start, temp_out(k)(m), add_over(k)(m));
                end generate;   
        end generate;

        g2: for k in 0 to 1 generate
                g3: for m in 0 to 1 generate
                        check_all_done <= add_over(k)(m) and init_val;
                end generate;   
        end generate;

        p1_add:process(check_all_done,temp_out)
        begin
            AplusB <= temp_out;
            parallel_add_done <= check_all_done;            
        end process;

end Behavioral;
```

My package is as below

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

    package mat_pak is


    subtype small_int is integer range 0 to 2;

    type t22 is array (0 to 1) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    type t2 is array (0 to 1) of t22; --2*2 matrix

    type t22bit is array (0 to 1) of std_logic;
    type t2bit is array (0 to 1) of t22bit; --2*2 matrix bit

    type t33 is array (0 to 2) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    type t3 is array (0 to 2) of t33; --3*3 matrix

end mat_pak;
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logical issues with your design.

First, there's some maximum number of ports for a sub-hierarchy a design can tolerate, you have 192 'bits' of matrix inputs and outputs. Do you really believe this number should be configurable?

At some point it will only fit in the very large FPGA devices, and shortly thereafter not fit there either.

Imagining some operation taking a variable number of clocks in `add` and  `parallel_add_done` signifies when an `aplusb` datum is available comprised of elements of the matrix array contributed by all instantiated `add` components, the individual `rdy` signals are ANDed together. If the `add`s all take the same amount of time you could take the `rdy` from anyone of them (If you silicon is not that deterministic it would not be usable, there are registers in `add`).

The nested generate statements all assign the result of the AND between add_over(k,m) and `init_val` (which is a synthesis constant of `1`).  The effect or wire ANDing add_over(k.m) bits together (which doesn't work in VHDL and is likely not achievable in synthesis, either).

Note I also showed the proper indexing method for the two dimensional arrays.

Using  Jonathan's method of sizing matrixes:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package mat_pak is

    type matrix  is array (natural range <>, natural range <>)
               of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    type bmatrix is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) 
               of std_logic;                      
end package mat_pak;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.mat_pak.all;

entity newproj is
    generic ( size:  natural := 2 );
    port ( 
        clk:                in  std_logic;
        clr:                in  std_logic;
        start:              in  std_logic;
        a_in:               in  matrix (0 to size - 1, 0 to size - 1);
        b_in:               in  matrix (0 to size - 1, 0 to size - 1);
        aplusb:             out matrix (0 to size - 1, 0 to size - 1);
        parallel_add_done:  out std_logic
    );
end entity newproj;

architecture behavioral of newproj is
    component add
        port (
            a:      in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            b:      in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            clk:    in  std_logic;
            sclr:   in  std_logic;
            ce:     in  std_logic;
            result: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            rdy:    out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal temp_out: matrix (0 to size - 1, 0 to size - 1) 
                :=  (others => (others => (others => '0')));
    signal add_over: bmatrix (0 to size - 1, 0 to size - 1)
                := (others => (others => '0'));
begin
g0: 
    for k in  0 to size - 1 generate 
g0x: 
        for m in 0 to size - 1 generate
            add_instx: add 
                port map (
                    a => a_in(k,m),
                    b => b_in(k,m),
                    clk => clk,
                    sclr => clr,
                    ce => start,
                    result => temp_out(k,m),
                    rdy => add_over(k,m)
                );
        end generate;   
    end generate;

    aplusb <= temp_out;

p1_add:
    process (add_over)
        variable check_all_done: std_logic;
    begin
        check_all_done := '1';
        for k in 0 to size - 1 loop
            for m in 0 to size -1 loop
                check_all_done := check_all_done and add_over(k,m);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        parallel_add_done <= check_all_done;
    end process;

end architecture behavioral;
```

We find that we really want to AND the various `rdy` outputs (`add_over` array) together.  In VHDL -2008 this can be done with the unary AND, otherwise you're counting on a synthesis tool to flatten the AND (and they generally do).

I made the assignment to `aplusb` a concurrent assignment.

So I dummied up an `add` entity with an empty architecture, the above then analyzes, elaborates and simulates, which shows that none of the connectivity has length mismatches anywhere.

Comment: Hello David Koontz,

Thank you very much for your inputs and alternate solution.  Matrix addition is one part of a larger code. At the highest level, the number of inputs and outputs will be well within the 388 bonded IOB's that Virtex 6 provides. I hope it is thus safe to have these many input ports (100 in the present case). If it is still unacceptable and not synthesizable, I will have to look at some other way to get the same functionality. Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure to understand perfectly, but I'll try to answer anyway ;)

You can use unconstrained array like this:

```
package mat_pak is
  type matrix is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
end package mat_pack;

entity newproj is
Generic ( size : natural );
Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       clr : in  STD_LOGIC;
       start : in  STD_LOGIC;
       A_in : in  matrix(0 to size-1, 0 to size-1);
       B_in : in  matrix(0 to size-1, 0 to size-1);
       AplusB : out  matrix(0 to size-1, 0 to size-1);
       parallel_add_done : out  STD_LOGIC);
end newproj;
```

Comment: Hello Jonathan Drolet, Thank you very much for your suggestion of using unconstrained array. I learnt something new and extremely useful from your input. Thanks once again.